# I am getting an AttributeError when I try to resize an image I have inserted to a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an image I inserted in my Tkinter window, but keep receiving this error message: "AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'"
This is my code to resize the image:

```
    self.path = 'S:/Öffentliche Ordner/Logos/Core Solution/Logo/CoreSolution_Logo_RGB.jpg'
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.path))
    self.resized = self.img.resize(50,50)
    self.new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized)

    self.label = Label(master, image = self.new_img)
    self.label.pack()
    self.Main = Frame(self.master)
```

How can I resolve this error? All help is welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As in this tutorial, it looks like it is easier to import the file as an image. Then resize it, then convert it to PhotoImage. Can you give it a try ?

```
# Import the required libraries
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
win=Tk()

# Set the size of the tkinter window
win.geometry("700x350")

# Load the image
image=Image.open('download.png')

# Resize the image in the given (width, height)
img=image.resize((450, 350))

# Conver the image in TkImage
my_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

# Display the image with label
label=Label(win, image=my_img)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/resizing-images-with-imagetk-photoimage-with-tkinter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that copying content from tutorialspoint and republishing it here is illegal (it's a copyright violation as mentioned in their [terms of use](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/about_terms_of_use.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the Pillow Image.PhotoImage class is meant for displaying in tkinter but does not have all the methods of the tkinter.PhotoImage class.

Easiest is to resize the Pillow.Image before converting to Pillow Image.PhotoImage.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = Tk()

path = 'images/cleese.png'
img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail((50,50))      # Resize Pillow Image
new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)   # Convert

label = Label(master, image=new_img)
label.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I did not test.

```
path = Image.open('S:/Öffentliche Ordner/Logos/Core Solution/Logo/CoreSolution_Logo_RGB.jpg'
self.resized = path.resize{(50,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)
self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized)

self.label = Label(master, image = self.new_img)
self.label.pack()
self.Main = Frame(self.master)
```